# OpenNI Samples on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kinect, openni, point-cloud-library

I just installed OpenNI so that I can run my Kinect on Ubuntu and develop there as well and it seems to be working properly but when I run the samples it just says starting to run and then never moves forward.  I believe it is working properly because the Kinect is on and the infrared light is on so it is operating but I am not sure what to do to run the sample or collect the data in the proper way.

When I run the NiSampleSkeleton it just gets stuck at starting to run... and when I try to run NiSimpleViewer from the [docs](http://openni.org/docs2/Reference/samples.html)  it freezes up completely and I have to restart my computer.  Should it just run properly right off the bat after I have the basics installed or do I need to add any additional programs?

Right now I have the OpenNi Source Binary, the NITE binary, and the PrimeSensor module all the unstable build for Ubuntu 64 bit all from the [OpenNi Download Page](http://www.openni.org/Downloads/OpenNIModules.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried gathering data with `strace`?  It might provide valuable insight into what it's doing when it's not generating the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the sample using the stable release for 64 bit Linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

OpenNI doens't support Kinect for Linux anymore, what you can do is use a bind of libfrenect driver and openNI that you can found [here](https://github.com/piedar/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver). If you are already using this bind maybe the problem are some kind of permission issues. In that case there is a solution [here](https://github.com/piedar/OpenNI2-FreenectDriver/issues/6).